# From two tables from my database i would like to echo a column with click counts

Tags: php, mysqli

In my database i have created two tables , the one is "categories" and the other "click_count". 
The two tables have the following information : categories( cat_id, cat_name , cat_description ) and click_count(id, cat_id, cat_count). I have already written a php code which echo a table with information about categories and i have already written a php code whick calculates the click counts, so i want a php script which i can echo on the same table the information about click_count and specify the "cat_count" which contains the number about "clicks" . The following code is obviously wrong but you can get the logic.

```
<?php
$sql4 = "SELECT categories.cat_id,categories.cat_name,click_count.cat_id,click_count.cat_count WHERE categories.cat_id=click_count.cat_id";  
$result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)) {
echo '<td>'.$row4['cat_count'];  }?>
```

Comment: can you provide sample out put you are looking for ?

Comment: I am building a forum website which on the first page have a table, on the first column is the names of the categories, the second column is the  category description and on the third column i want the numbers of the views(clicks). As i say i have already build the table in database and the php script which calculates the sum of the clicks but i don't know how to put the numbers of the clicks on the table. I am assuming that i must learn JOINS methods .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT statement should contain a JOIN:

```
SELECT categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, click_count.cat_id, click_count.cat_count 
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN click_count 
ON categories.cat_id = click_count.cat_id;
```

...and you can also add a WHERE clause at the end if you need it to select not all, but only the ones that fit a certain condition.

Comment: Ok perfect i will try this, thank you. Is the "mysqli_fetch_assoc" is the right function ?